# How do I take the result of something and use it

Tags: java

I'm trying to take the answer of my multiply code and then

store it in a local variable called result

```
public int multiply(int x, int y) {
    return (x*y);      
}
```

is what I have so far.

After testing it, I get the answers to some multiplication problems but I can't think of how to store the answers

Comment: `int result = multiply(2,3);`

Comment: @BoristheSpider Now now, there are some who care little for aesthetically beautiful code.

Comment: @Sacert I'm not asking for _beautiful_ code, I am asking for _legible_ code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider They are one and the same in my books ;)

Comment: Do you want to store the result temporarily, during the execution of your application, or do you want to store the results in the file system for later use?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a variable that it can be stored in to and then declare that variable with the function like so: `int result = multiple(3,4);`

Comment: I tried that but just get "unreachable statement"

Comment: Where are you declaring this variable? You will only get an unreachable statement if you declared it in a position where the compiler will never read. Make sure that wherever it is that it can be reached at least once.

Comment: public int multiply(int x, int y)





   {
      return (x*y);
       int result = multiply(x,y);   
     
                     }

Comment: Do not put `int result = multiple(3,4);` within your multiply function. Put it where you need it to be run which might be within your `main` function.

Answer (score -1):

find my Test class

```
public class Test {

    public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
        return x * y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int result = multiply(4,5);
    }

}
```

Comment: It' s useless to declare 'c' variable in your method.

Comment: Asakura , u r correct, thanks

Comment: If you are going to use C-style brackets, use them **everywhere**. If you are going to use Egyptian brackets, use them **everywhere**. Never mix and match formatting. Consistency is next to cleanliness...